# How do I arrange loops?

Tags: python, loops

I am new to Python programming. I am trying to make a program that helps sailors quickly calculate their speed, time, and distance using the handy formula `S * T = D`

I created If statements based on the answer, as you will see below.

Main questions:

how could this code be cleaned up?

Why do I, even when a correct answer like "speed" is input, receive the answer I used for the `else`? (i.e., even when a user chooses "speed," the output still says he didn't choose one of the three options).

How do I incorporate a loop into my program so that if the user inputs a wrong answer it goes right back to the initial question?

Thank you!

I've tried adding the `def()` before the `if` statements and it doesn't work. I've also tried doing `while True` in various locations.

```
name = raw_input("what's your name?")
print 'Hi ' + name + ' you landlubber, you.'
# This will tell me whether we want to find out Speed, time, or distance
answer = raw_input("Do you want to figure out your speed, distance, or   time? Choose one and hit 'Enter'").lower()
# This will determine the response to their choice.
if answer == "speed":
print "You is all about that speed eh?"
if answer == "distance":
print "It's all about the journey, not the destination."
if answer == "time":
print "Time is an illusion, bro."
else:
print "You didn't choose one of the three options"
```

Comment: your indentation is quite wrong, part of the problem may be derived from that

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, long strings of `if/elif` are difficult to maintain and difficult to read.

A better way might be to use a dictionary to map input to output. Then all the input -> response mappings are in one easy-to-read place — they can even be imported from a different file. The logic to decide what to say is then a simple dictionary lookup. You can use `get()` to provide a default for the cases when the value isn't in the dictionary. For example:

```
# map input to output:
responses = {
    "speed": "You is all about that speed eh?",
    "distance": "It's all about the journey, not the destination.",
    "time": "Time is an illusion, bro."
}

name = raw_input("what's your name?")
print('Hi ' + name + ' you landlubber, you.')

# This will tell me whether we want to find out Speed, time, or distance
answer = raw_input("Do you want to figure out your speed, distance, or   time? Choose one and hit 'Enter'").lower()

# just lookup the response:
print(responses.get(answer, "You didn't choose one of the three options"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. This was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question, and the answer is you need to use: `if, elif, elif, else`.  You can have as many `elif`'s as you want, but Python will only pick exactly ONE of the `if, elif, else` blocks to run.

Also I added `.strip()` to your input to clear off spaces.

```
name = raw_input("what's your name?")
print 'Hi ' + name + ' you landlubber, you.'

# This will tell me whether we want to find out Speed, time, or distance
answer = raw_input("Do you want to figure out your speed, distance, or time?   Choose one and hit 'Enter'").lower().strip()

# This will determine the response to their choice.
if answer == "speed":
    print "You is all about that speed eh?"
elif answer == "distance":
   print "It's all about the journey, not the destination."
elif answer == "time":
   print "Time is an illusion, bro."
else:
   print "You didn't choose one of the three options"
```